# activerecord - calling a setter without firing the getter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, recursion

This is a pretty simple method (in `Member.rb` in Rails 4).
I am overriding a getter for an active record attribute.

```
def score
  self.update(score: compute_score)
  super
end

def compute_score
 ... some unrelated math ... 
end
```

hopefully the idea is clear, im trying to update the score every time it is read. When I run this, though, I get stuck in a recursive loop. The `self.update(score: compute_score)` seems to call the custom `score` method I defined again. I also tried `self.score =`, `self[:score] =`, and `write_attribute`, but the same result is produced. How can I avoid this recursion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** have to update a field when you retrieve the record, then use [after_initialize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) in  ActiveRecord Callbacks

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_initialize :compute_score
  ...

  def compute_score
    ...
  end

end
```

I think it's better to compute at `before_save` unless `score` depends on some external factors (such as third-party APIs). And if you have to compute at the point of retrieval, use a virtual attribute.

Comment: hey thanks. using a virtual attribute (or simply naming the getter method something besides the actual db column) is something i hadn't considered, that seems like a good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `update_attribute` ie instead of

```
self.update(score: compute_score)
```

try:

```
self.update_attribute(:score, compute_score)
```

The difference is `update_attribute` skips all validation and I assume that's where getter is called.